# Best practice to persist a RPC request content

Tags: java, oracle, rpc

We have a SOA application which provides hundreds of rpc services. For some of those rpc services, we want to persist the incoming request content to database. as you can see, the structure and request arguments are different from services to services, we can not design a standard structure table to contain the entire request body.

Oracle 11 is the only persist store we can use and we can not use nosql/distributed cache products. we have been considered using json and clob fields to achieve this requirement, but due to performance reason, our DBA suggests that use clob is not a good idea.

i am wondering is there anyone have the similar situation and is there any best practice to do this?

Comment: How long would the json string be?  greater than 4000 bytes?  greater than 8000 bytes?  what is the average size?

Comment: I would say it depends, we have been considered splitting those request contents into several 4000 bytes fields, but we dont think this is a very nice design :( just wondering is there any other best practice to achive this

Comment: splitting is not a great plan, but, since you are handcuffed to Oracle 11, it may be a reasonable option.  Step 1 is to determine what size of JSON to expect so you can plan a reasonable solution.  If 90% of the json is less than 4000 characters (after you strip unnecessary white space from it), then one or two VARCHAR2(4000) columns may be reasonable.  Given the choice, I'd suggest MySql (or Maria) and a large varchar column (based on expected json size).  In MySql you can have up to 65535 in one column (with limitations).

Answer (score 0):

We have applications which persist the message going across the messaging oriented middleware (as I recall, on the order of 30 million messages a month requiring about 1 TB tablespace to manage this with deletions of old messages > 42 days old [it would have been much easier if they used partitioning and truncate to manage space]).  It simply does an insert with the message going into a CLOB and recording other relevant message metadata in columns of appropriate datatype and size [I think they used to tables a message metadata table and a message payload table; they query the message metadata table for basic metrics on how their service is being used].  From my notes to the client:

**LOB Storage Basics:**
 1. The LOB segment is bigger than just the sum of the bytes of the
    messages
 2. Each LOB can be stored in-line or out-of-line.
In-line means that LOBs up to 3964 bytes are stored in the same block of the table (segment) with the rest of the data for that row. LOBs bigger than 3964 bytes get stored out-of-line in a LOB segment. 
Out-of-line LOBs are completely stored in a LOB segment with only a lob locators stored in the block with the rest of the row.

The chunk size determines how the data gets stored out-of-line; this is the LOB segment space allocation unit for each LOB regardless of size. So for each LOB, you get a multiple of the chunk size needed for that LOB.  So this leads to some amount of wastage for most LOBs.

**LOB Free Space Usage:**
RETENTION for lob space management should allow the entire lob segment to be used over time [I believe the behavior is: when a block in a lob segment is freed by delete, it goes on the free list after the UNDO_RETENTION period (15 min for [instance A])]; this is a better implementation as it does not set aside a fixed percent of space to be used like PCTVERSION will.

Additionally, Oracle’s consistent read (CR) mechanism for LOB segments uses the LOB segment itself (rather than the UNDO tablespace as most CR’s do).  So, this too results in the LOB segment requiring some extra space to support CR.

**Optimization scenarios include:**
1.  In-line storage can improve performance for the following reasons:
a.  LOB data smaller than 3964 bytes is cached in the buffer cache. 
b.  LOB data larger than 3964 bytes is accessed via direct path reads/writes (i.e. faster I/O)
2.  Chunk-size can be made smaller to have less space wastage, but there are some caveats: 
a.  The tablespace the CLOB is currently in has an 8K DB block size and chunk size is a multiple of DB block size so it can only be made smaller in a tablespace with smaller block size.
b.  A smaller chunk size means more work for reading and writing and you pay a performance penalty on the larger size entries. Median message size is right at 3900 characters, to factor in the multi-byte character set, the middle value is about 8K chars.  Therefore, going to a smaller chunk will mean most data will require at least 2 accesses [actual time not determined]. A new tablespace would be populated by moving the CLOB to it [requiring down-time], accomplishing the same as the shrink, and would let us see the impact.
3.  LOB Reorganization:  not recommended at this time since purged space from deleted rows is being re-used.

More info on LOBs can be found in the LOB Performance Guidelines White Paper.

**Other Options:** 
 1. Use 11g LOB datatype SecureFile In 11g the LOB data type has been
    redesigned completely. To use SecureFile LOB storage, it is done
    declaratively in the storage clause of the table create statement. 
 2. look into Advanced Compression for reducing space requirements
 3. look into Partitioning for improved manageability

Comment: thanks for the response. actually our application has 15 million requests per day and we are asked to persist those records for a year :( and this "No lobs" instruction is from our development guide which we can do nothing about. Our DBAs believe that it is not a good idea to use lobs in a busy oltp system.

Comment: Ok. @raging_sweet  It's all about meeting the requirements within the design/implementation constraints.  The only other guidance I would offer is from my experience as an enterprise architect, very few applications would build scalability / stress tests that correctly model the projected application behavior, so in my mind, another best practice would be to have that performance test harness that could be run as say 10% of full load, working up to > 100% of full expected load.